# Running a python script inside an nginx docker container

Tags: python, docker, nginx

I'm using nginx to serve some of my docs. I have a python script that processes these docs for me. I don't want to pre-process the docs and then add them in before the docker container is built since these docs can grow to be pretty big and they increase in number. What I want is to run my python (and bash) scripts inside the nginx container and have nginx just serve those docs. Is there a way to do this without pre-processing the docs before building the container?
I've attempted to execute `RUN python3 process_docs.py`, but I keep seeing the following error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: python: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c python process_docs.py' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Is there a way to get python3 onto the Nginx docker container? I was thinking of installing python3 using:

```
apt-get update -y
apt-get install python3.6 -y
```

but I'm not sure that this would be good practice. Please let me know the best way to run my pre processing script.

Comment: To answer properly we need to know where these containers are running? Docker compose, swarm, kubernetes, something else? The container orchestrator most probably offers an established pattern to do this.

Comment: Building using `docker build -t docs:v1 .`  Running using: `docker run -d --name=docs-web -p 3009:80 docs:v1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) to inject data from your host system into the container.  This will automatically update itself when the host data changes.  If you're running this in Docker Compose, the syntax looks like

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./data:/usr/share/nginx/html/data
    ports:
      - '8000:80'  # access via http://localhost:8000
```

In this sample setup, the `html` directory holds your static assets (checked into source control) and the `data` directory holds the generated data.  You can regenerate the data *from the host*, outside Docker, the same way you would if Docker weren't involved

```
# on the host
. venv/bin/activate
./regenerate_data.py --output-directory ./data
```

You should not need `docker exec` in normal operation, though it can be extremely useful as a debugging tool.  Conceptually it might help to think of a container as identical to a process; if you ask "can I run this Python script inside the Nginx *process*", no, you should generally run it somewhere else.